# Chrome extension, how to send message from panel to content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

My contentScript sends a message to backgroundScript which opens a popup/panel/window. This panel loads an external web page.
I'm injecting some javascript in the panel to interact with it.

What I'm trying do achieve now is to send data from the panel to the 'main page' (contentScript).
I have successfully managed to send messages from the panel to the backgroundScript.

What I don't understand/know is how to pass the data from the backgoundScript to the contentScript.

**Updated script from @Haibara Ai's comment**

**manifest.js**

```
{
"name": "My extension",
"version": "0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "description",
"permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs","http://*/*","https://*/*"],
"content_scripts": [
    {
        // Change 'matches' attribute to load content
        // script only in pages you want to.
        "matches": ["SomeUrl"],
        "js": ["jquery.min.js", "contentscript.js", "notifier.js"]
    }
],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
}
}
```

**contentscript.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var link = document.getElementById('inputLink');

    // onClick's logic below:
    link.addEventListener('click', function() {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            action: 'createWindow',
            url: $('input[name=link]').val()
          }, function(message) {
            console.log(message);
            })
    });
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) { 
    alert('a');
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
});
```

**eventPage.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
    if (request && request.action === 'createWindow' && request.url) {
        chrome.windows.create(
            {
                url: request.url,
                focused: true,
                incognito: true,
                type: "panel"
            }, function (newWindow) {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(newWindow.tabs[0].id, {
                    file: "jquery.min.js"
                }, function() {
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(newWindow.tabs[0].id, {
                        file: "htmlselection.js"
                    });
                });
                chrome.tabs.insertCSS(newWindow.tabs[0].id, {file: "htmlselection.css"});
        });
    } else {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
            console.log(chrome.tabs);
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "SendIt"}, function(response) {});  
        });
    }
});
```

**htmlselection.js** (injected in the popup/panel/window)

```
[...]
//After a click within the popup/panel/window
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ text: 'test' });
[...]
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

### Updated

If you want to send message inside `chrome.runtime.onMessage`, just use the callback `sendResponse` or use `sender.tab.id` as tabId to send back the message.

And there are other problems with your code:

1. Since you are use [Programming injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi) to inject script, you should declare them in `"web_accessible_resources"` in `manifest.json`

   ```
   "web_accessible_resources": [
       "htmlselection.js",
       "jquery.min.js",
       "htmlselection.css"
   ]
   ```
2. In your contentscript.js, just remove message part, since you didn't receive anything in this script.
3. For eventpage.js, use `sendResponse` instead of `tab.query`.

   ```
   else {
       console.log("2");
       sendResponse({ action: "SendIt" });
   }
   ```

### Previous

Take a look at [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple), you could send a message from background page using the following code snippets:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide more info please? Like where should this snippet be called?

Comment: @Kaymaz, this snippet should be called in background page

Comment: it appears that `tabs` only contains the current popup/panel.
I added a `chrome.runtime.addListener` but it doesn't receive any message. I updated my question.

Comment: With the `sendRespone`, I'm replying to my popup, not my main page (contentScript).
So I do:
MainPage --> eventPage <--> popup

Comment: @Kaymaz, then what about setting `focused: false` when creating new window? Or saving the tabId as a local cache when receiving message from MainPage, and reuse it when send back message.

Answer (score -2):

Fixed version of the snippet:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: false}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
  });
});
```

Set the `currentWindow:false` and it worked.

Comment: This answer is not correct, `currentWindow: false` will return any window which is not current active, see my answer.